# CAS Disable Service X-Frame-Options not work

Tags: cas, x-frame-options

I have setup a CAS server as a SSO solution for several websites.
I use JSON files as the service registry. However, I would like to disable the X-Frame-Options for one of the websites only, as it is a legacy website using iframe to embed some modules in it. For security reason, I don't want to disable the X-Frame-Options in other websites.
I setup the CAS successfully for those websites, however, I cannot disable the X-Frame-Options for that particular legacy website.

The CAS version is 5.3 and I use the configuration mentioned in CAS official website here:
https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/Configuring-Service-Http-Security-Headers.html
And here is my JSON file that legacy website:

```
{
  "@class": "org.apereo.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService",
  "serviceId": "^https://my-internal-site.com.*",
  "name": "mysite",
  "id": 1001,
  "evaluationOrder": 5,
  "attributeReleasePolicy": {
    "@class": "org.apereo.cas.services.ReturnMappedAttributeReleasePolicy",
    "authorizedToReleaseProxyGrantingTicket": true,
    "allowedAttributes": {
      "@class": "java.util.TreeMap",
      "username": "username",
      "personUuid": "personUuid"
    }
  },
  "proxyPolicy": {
    "@class": "org.apereo.cas.services.RegexMatchingRegisteredServiceProxyPolicy",
    "pattern": "^https://.+"
  },
  "properties" : {
    "@class" : "java.util.HashMap",
    "httpHeaderEnableXFrameOptions" : {
      "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.services.DefaultRegisteredServiceProperty",
      "values" : [ "java.util.HashSet", [ "false" ] ]
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried to see the configuration through the CAS Dashboard and found that CAS has recognized my configuration and I can see the configuration of httpHeaderEnableXFrameOptions in "mysite".
However, I still cannot disable the X-Frame-Options for my legacy website (mysite).
Is there anything wrong in my configuration? Or is there any other configuration I need to setup in order to disable the X-Frame-Options for only that legacy websites?
Thanks

Comment: Also, make sure the serviceId is ends with a slash `^https://my-internal-site.com/.*`, otherwise the URI can be spoofed. E.g. `^https://my-internal-site.com.malicoius.site.can.be.injected.here/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked into the code for you, see these two location that determind whether or not **X-Frame-Options** is in effect or not:

- https://github.com/apereo/cas/blob/v5.3.14/core/cas-server-core-web-api/src/main/java/org/apereo/cas/services/web/support/RegisteredServiceResponseHeadersEnforcementFilter.java#L57
- https://github.com/apereo/cas-server-security-filter/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apereo/cas/security/ResponseHeadersEnforcementFilter.java#L281

Merging the two source together and some paraphrasing, and we got this:

### The logic for whether **X-Frame-Options** is enabled / disabled

```java
    @Override
    protected void decideInsertXFrameOptionsHeader(final HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        // Check A
        if (shouldHttpHeaderBeInjectedIntoResponse(httpServletRequest,
            RegisteredServiceProperties.HTTP_HEADER_ENABLE_XFRAME_OPTIONS)) {
            final String xFrameOptions = getStringProperty(httpServletRequest, RegisteredServiceProperties.HTTP_HEADER_XFRAME_OPTIONS);
            super.insertXFrameOptionsHeader(httpServletResponse, httpServletRequest, xFrameOptions);
        } else {
             // Check B
             if (!this.enableXFrameOptions) {
                 return;
             }
             insertXFrameOptionsHeader(httpServletResponse, httpServletRequest);
        }
    }
```

### Analyze the logic

There are 2 ways to influence the result of whether or not xframe option is enabled:

1. **this.enableXFrameOptions**, which is cas.httpWebRequest.header.xframe in [here](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/Configuration-Properties.html#http-web-requests)
2. **httpHeaderEnableXFrameOptions in service**, which is already linked in the question

If we make a table showing how setting the above 2 values will influence the ultimate result of showing XFrameOptions or not:

```
+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|  enableXFrameOptions property  |  httpHeaderEnableXFrameOptions in service |  Is XFrame Enabled? |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|         true                   |                 true                      |        true         |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|         false                  |                 true                      |        true         |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|         true                   |                 false                     |       *true*        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|         false                  |                 false                     |        false        |
+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+---------------------+
```

That's why in your case, when you set:

1. **this.enableXFrameOptions** = true (by default)
2. **httpHeaderEnableXFrameOptions in service** = false

Result is still **true**, hence what you see in the result.

### Solution

One dumb solution (not tested) is to set `cas.httpWebRequest.header.xframe` to false,
and make sure all your service is marked with `httpHeaderEnableXFrameOptions = true` expect of course the legacy website

Another solution would to be make custom change to CAS to modified this behavior

Or maybe there are some other solution, if so maybe other can helps :)